# Android Firebase Send Push Notification When New Data Added

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is the structure of my app's data in which user can log in and post the image with image's detail in the database.
I want that if a user post image, every user can see the notification **Seth Post Something** 
I cannot find any link how to send a notification to all users when new data is added.
Can anyone specify the roadmap, code snippet  how to do this after configuration of FCM

[image]

Comment: you can find info on this here http://www.zoftino.com/android-notification-data-messages-from-app-server-using-firebase-cloud-messaging

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your requirement you can use cloud function to send messages to all devices and the steps to achieve this.

1. take device access token for all user and save it in your database because without access token you can't send the message to devices never forget to update this toke whenever it changed.
2. cloud message will trigger always whenever any event occurs in a targeted part of the database.
3. For cloud message link of tutorials are here

[Fcm Tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref),
[cloud function Tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions)  and [this tutorial](https://aaronczichon.de/2017/03/13/firebase-cloud-functions/) is very helpful for me.

Comment: Sir tutorial you are mentioning is for nodejs. I think it will not work on Android

Comment: write your cloud function deploy it on firebase properly whenever any event occurred in your firebase database. Ex. if you create a new message in your firebase DB cloud function automatically trigger and whatever logic you write will execute and you can check logs of cloud function for checking cloud function working properly or not

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is registering your users to one topic.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("MySampleApp");
```

Then send a post request to fcm api https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
//HEADERS
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GB,./,Udno5aA

//BODY
{
  "to": "/topics/MySampleApp",
  "data": {
      "message": "Hello Everyone!",
  }
}
```

Then handle the notification in your FirebaseMessagingService. Hope this helps

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple     I find this link I wanna ask where should i write post request code

Comment: you send the request to firebase api which is  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send